# Netlify deploy with _redirects file not working for http api

Tags: reactjs, rest, deployment, netlify

Netlify deploy with _redirects file not working for http api.

After deploying my react app to netlify I encountered an issue caused by Netlify being on HTTPS protocol and the API that i'm trying to reach on HTTP - Mixed content. So I did some research that I have to proxy the API to be called over HTTPS and for that I have to use _redirects file.

`/base/* http://exampleapi.com/:splat 200`

And I restructured my endpoints to be like this:

`process.env.REACT_APP_NETLIFY + "/base/app/getById?" + urlParams`

When I deploy my site, I can even see that redirects file gets processed, but the error message remains.

`xhr.js:247 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://rahvatantsuk.netlify.app/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://eampleApi.com/app/getDances?accountId=4002'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

What's weird is that I thoguth I fixed this issue with redirects and it actually worked in production for a while but now I see this error once again. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soi I misunderstood netlifys docs and restructured the api string to be `"/base/app/getById?" + urlParams` and now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the `_redirects` file in your src folder and in the file add these line and try deploy `/*  /index.html 200`. It worked for me.

Comment: What would that do? Wouldn't that help with routing not api calls?

Comment: Sorry im not good at explaining. Please look in to [this](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/)

Answer (score 0):

you should make the environment variable and the value should be your API key

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).